# How to mute active browser tab programatically with JS tabs API?

Tags: javascript, tabs, firefox-addon, userscripts

I'm trying to build a simple userscript to automatically mute tabs matching a certain URL. I'm trying to start simple, just muting the active tab if it matches the URL. Here's the code I would expect to perform the mute action:

`browser.tabs.update({muted: true});`

But when I try to run it, nothing happens. From the [tabs.update documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/update) I know I don't have to specify a tab ID if I'm working with the active tab, but it also says that this function returns a Promise, and I'm not familiar with how that affects things. (Every example I can find of a Promise uses the `.then` method to call specific actions after the Promise is completed, e.g. writing console output. But I don't need anything to happen *afterwards*, I just want it to *happen*.)

Can anyone help figure out why this code isn't working?

(Note: I'm running userscripts on Firefox using the Firemonkey extension.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> browser.tabs.update({muted: true});

Above API is in browser scope (for browser & extensions) and is not available in `userScript` or `content` scope where user-scripts run.

In user-scripts, you need to use Web API.

Here is an idea that you can work on .... not tested

```js
document.querySelectorAll('audio, video').forEach(item => {
  item.muted = true;
  item.pause();
});
```

Comment: Will this work even if it's not necessarily an autoplaying media element on the page, but rather a JS-triggered audio event? (for example, the notification chime from the Facebook Messenger webpage when you receive a new message)

Comment: @ETL If the element does not exist at the time userscript runs, then you may have add a `MutationObserver` to look for when it is created.